# A maven build issue in org.apache.axis2.wso2 dependency

Tags: java, maven, wso2

I am trying to build a maven project and it consists of several dependencies. But the project becomes failure to build when I add org.apache.axis2.wso2  maven dependency into pom file and the Following error is showed up.

```
Failure to find org.apache.axis2.wso2:axis2-client:pom:1.6.1.wso2v10 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

My pom,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1.wso2v10</version>
</dependency>
```

Please, anyone, have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the message you need to force update your local repository against the central repository.

This can be done using the following mvn option (taken from mvn -h):

-U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for missing
                                        releases and updated snapshots on
                                        remote repositories

Try to run `mvn -U clean install`